# how to change default website loading page in vs2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I recently installed VS2017 and when I run the site, the following page is displayed after I F5 to load the site and displays until the actual webpage displays:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyzhegrsekib740/web-app-start-page.png?dl=0

I don't remember the behavior in the previous version of Visual Studio but I think that the default page was just white.  Do you know if there's a way to change the default page loading display to a blank page or something else?

Comment: You could right click your project, choose Properties > Web and set the Start Action to Don't open a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature of VS 2017 that enables [JavaScript debugging in Chrome](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/) inside VS. To turn it off:

> Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and turn off the setting Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).